# Did Corax really try to rescue Vulkan?

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

I've just finished reading Vulkan Lives from the Horus Heresy Series. Throughout it Curze tricks and tortures his prisoner but Vulkan is clearly not in the best mental state already. I've also read Deliverance Lost and Corax seemed to be rather busy at the time he was supposedly trying to aid his brother.

Did The Raven really try to rescue Vulkan or was it another of Curze's games?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

In *Vulkan Lives*, chapter 23, last paragraph:

> I came round screaming. I had returned to my cell, but still lay on my back. The door was intact and there was no evidence of my recent escape. I was strapped down to a metal slab, arms, legs and neck. I couldn’t move and there was a metal wedge in my mouth, gagging me. Surrounding me was a coven of human psykers, feral-looking with strange sigils daubed on their bodies and robes. ‘Davinites,’ Curze explained as he walked into my eye line, before killing every one of the witches in a sudden and violent blur. ‘They have served and failed their purpose,’ he said when he was done butchering them. It was all a lie – visions implanted in my mind. Curze removed the wedge from my mouth. ‘Did you expect me to kill him?’ I snarled. My brother looked profoundly unhappy. ‘You are not noble. You are no better than me,’ he muttered, before killing me again.

Comment: I assume the previous sections of this chapter and the "escape" are the rescues referred to in the question?

Comment: @Jontia Yes, the whole chapter is Corax trying to rescue Vulkan and having to fight him and after Vulkan not being able to kill Corax waking up as cited. Could not find any other reference to Corvus Corax in the book.